# Or keyword for pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I don't understand how to have the equivalent of `a = b or c` with pandas series.

MWE:

```
# basic python
b = None
c = 'not None'
a = b or c
assert a == c

# expected behaviour in pandas
df = pd.DataFrame({'b' : [None, 'not None'], 'c': ['not None', 'other']})
df.assign(a=lambda df: df.b | df.c)

# raise TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to get the result you want:

```
df['a'] = df.b.fillna(df.c)
print (df)
          b         c         a
0      None  not None  not None
1  not None     other  not None
```

where the value is `None` in `b` then the value of `c` is considered

Answer (score 3):

Using `bfill` in case you have more than two columns

```
df['a']=df.bfill(1).b
df
Out[16]: 
          b         c         a
0      None  not None  not None
1  not None     other  not None
```